# Regular expression for extracting substring in the middle of a string

Tags: regex

Looking for a regular expression that extracts multiple characters, at different locations, in my string. For example, the string I'm working with is `5490028400316201600008` and it will always be this same length, but the numbers can change.
I would like to extract the first 9 characters, then skip the next 8, extract the next 4, then ignore the last character. The resulting string would be `5490028400000` in this case. I can't seem to find an easy way to do this and I'm fairly new to regular expressions. Thanks in advance for your advice/help.

Comment: Do you actually need regular expressions? Seems more like a case for standard string operations in whatever language you use.

Comment: Welcome to So ! 
I suggest you learn about regex from [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info). Also mention in which programming language you are doing this. At last post your code or attempt in solving this question.

Comment: Yo do not need regex, you can just say something like final_str=str[0:9]+str[18:22]+str[22:-1]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this seems more appropiate for substring functions, they are usually faster and not so error-prone. However, for a learning purpose, you could come up with sth. like:

```
(.{9}).{8}(.{4}).
```

This matches *any* (not only digits, that is - for digits use `\d` instead) character 9 times, saves it in a group, matches another 8 characters which will not be saved, and will finally match another 4 characters into the second group.
Concenate `$1` and `$2` (5490028400000 in your case) and you should be fine.
See this [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uV9qS9/2).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and suggestions. The language I'm using is C++, so I'm not sure if the above/below suggestions will work. Thanks for the "regular-expressions.info" link, I will definitely give this a look as well.

Comment: I'm making a little progress on this, and I'm using "(^\d{9})" to capture the first 9 characters in my string. Now, I just need to find a way to capture characters 18-21. The software that I'm using,only allows me to enter in a regular expression, I'm not allowed to concatenate using $1 or $2. Therefore, is there a simple expression I can add to mine, that grabs whichever numbers are in position 18-21?